# How do I keep my image on the left side and my content on the right?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a simple website. I'm trying to display the image on the left side and the text content on the right. However, if there is more lines of text than the height of the image, the text carries over to the image's side. Can anyone help me fix this? Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YA2nv.jpg) of what I have right now, and what I'm talking about. Below is the CSS and HTML I'm using.

```css
/* Please do ignore .choices and #questions, that's for something else, not related to the question */
#questions > .question, #languages > .language{
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 75%;
}
.choices > .choice, #languages > .language{
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 16px;
}
#questions, #languages{
    margin-bottom: 48px;
}
#languages > .language{
    margin-top: 8px;
}
.language > img{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 24px;
    padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="javascript" class="language">
  <img src="images/logo/js.png">
  <div class="content">
    <section class="overview">    
      <h2>Overview</h2>
      <p></p>
    </section>
    <section class="comparison">
      <h3>Pros</h3>
      <ul class="pros">
        <li>Executed on the client side, which means you don't have to worry about your server being overworked</li>  <li>Easy to pickup, syntax is similar to the English language</li><li>Webpages can be easily extended</li></ul> <h3>Cons</h3>
      <ul class="cons">
        <li>Easily exploited</li>
        <li>Rendered differently throughout different browsers</li>  
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest method is to insert this to make you `#javascript` element a flexbox container:

```
#javascript {
  display: flex; 
  }
```

```css
/* Please do ignore .choices and #questions, that's for something else, not related to the question */

#questions > .question,
#languages > .language {
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 75%;
}
.choices > .choice,
#languages > .language {
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 16px;
}
#questions,
#languages {
  margin-bottom: 48px;
}
#languages > .language {
  margin-top: 8px;
}
.language > img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 24px;
  padding: 12px;
}
#javascript {
  display: flex; 
  }
```

```html
<div id="javascript" class="language">
  <img src="images/logo/js.png">
  <div class="content">
    <section class="overview">
      <h2>Overview</h2>
      <p></p>
    </section>
    <section class="comparison">
      <h3>Pros</h3>
      <ul class="pros">
        <li>Executed on the client side, which means you don't have to worry about your server being overworked</li>
        <li>Easy to pickup, syntax is similar to the English language</li>
        <li>Webpages can be easily extended</li>
      </ul>
      <h3>Cons</h3>
      <ul class="cons">
        <li>Easily exploited</li>
        <li>Rendered differently throughout different browsers</li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, that did not solve my problem. I get [this](http://imgur.com/4v7Q25k) now. I want the pros and cons lists to be in the right column, whereas the image will have the entire left column to itself.

Comment: Ah, I understand. I edited my answer: same principle (flexbox) now applied to the `#javascript` container - that should work the way you want it.

Comment: With a bit of editing you helped me get it to work. Thank you.